# Accessing a custom class in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following class in my rails application:

```
class Global
  class << self

    def method_missing(message)
      ENV[message.to_s]
    end

    def SOME_ENV_VAR
      ENV['SOME_ENV_VAR'].present? ? ENV['SOME_ENV_VAR'].to_i * 5 : nil
    end
end
```

Then I access all of my environment variables through this class which allows me to wrap any logic around an environment variable in one place. Is there a way I can access my Global class in the database.yml like so?

```
development:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= Global.DATABASE_URL || "the_database" %>
```

Comment: I _think_ that if you put this `Global` class in the `config/initializers/` folder it will be loaded at boot time and (hopefully) before the DB connection setup

Comment: You could try to initialize your code in a `before_configuration` callback, see, e.g., http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events

Comment: I tried both of these options and while I think I could maybe get them to work in conjunction I believe I found an easier solution, which I've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I found to this problem was requiring the `/app/global/global.rb` class from the `/config/application.rb` file.

```
require_relative '../app/global/global'

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # all of the general setup
  end
end
```